# Rotas filhas no angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, rotas

Olá, estou encontrando problemas com minhas rotas filhas.

Segue meus roteamentos:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'Login', component: Login },
    { path: 'Cadastro', component: CadastroUser, children: 
        [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dados-pessoais', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dados-pessoais', component: DadosPessoais},
            { path: 'bancos', component: CadastroBancos}
        ] 
    }
]
```

Estou tendo problemas nas rotas filhas do path: 'Cadastro'.

O problema é que eu estou dentro da rota: 'cadastro/dados-pessoais', e criei um botão desta forma:

```
<button class="btn" [routerLink]="['bancos']">Proximo Passo</button>
```

Para assim ir para a rota: 'cadastro/bancos'.

Porém esse erro é apresentado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha chamada do outlet fica assim:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guilherme, sua rota está para `/cadastro/bancos` e não para `/cadastro/dados-pessoais/bancos` conforme está sendo enviado.
Altera o seu botão para redirecionar para

```
['/cadastro/bancos']
```

ou cria um novo children nos dados pessoais:

```
 { path: 'dados-pessoais', component: DadosPessoais , children:
    [
       { path: 'bancos', component: CadastroBancos}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Alterei o botão como dito acima e o retorno foi: ' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cadastro/bancos''

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes tens o <base href="./">  no index.html ?

Comment: Sim. desta mesma forma.

Comment: tenta alterar para Cadastro/bancos , com o c maíusculo.

Comment: Agora foi! rsrs, que vacilo meu rsrs, obrigado

Comment: heheh eu tmb não reparei isso heheh ! Valeu ! :D